# Adding a record's attribute to the URL before the ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to add a specific attribute of a record in Rails to the URL from something like:

```
domain.com/share/5
```

(where `5` is the record ID) to something like:

```
domain.com/share/johnsmith/5
```

where `johnsmith` is stored in record `5`. I'm alternating between these two routes to no success:

```
get "/share/:name/:id" => "share#show"
resources :share, :only => [:show]
```

And between these two methods:

```
share_path(doc.user.name, doc)
share_path(doc)
```

The show method in the `ShareController` is pretty standard.

---

**The problem:**

Using `share_path(doc.user.name, doc)` in the view generates a link to `/share/johnsmith.5`, instead of `/share/johnsmith/5`.

Comment: What your `rake routes` tell you? :)

Comment: any error or something? what does rake routes tell you about your routes?, for the path, maybe you need to modify the "to_param" method of the doc object

Comment: The URL itself the function gives off is `domain.com/share/johnsmith.5` which is obviously wrong. `rake routes` just gives me this `GET    /share/:name/:id(.:format)                   share#show`.

Comment: Whre this `:ftp` came from?

Comment: Ah, `:ftp` should be `:name`, sorry. I changed it to make it easier to understand the question.

Comment: Could you try: `share_path(:name => doc.user.ftp, :id => doc)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what happened but it resolved itself with this:

```
get "/share/:name/:id" => "share#show", :as => :share
share_path(doc.user.name, doc)
```

I do not get the `.` and `/` issue at all. I restarted everything and it was gone.

Answer (score 1):

`get "/share/:name/:id" => "share#show"` should do the job. But you may have to look at the order of routes in `routes.rb`, maybe Rails took the wrong route?

Best tip to look at what's happening:

Call the URL in your browser (or using `curl` or whatever) and then look into your console where your started `rails s` (or `rails server`).

There you should see something like this:

```
Processing by ShareController#show
Parameters: {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"johnsmith"}
```

Concerning the `path` methods:

Simply use `rake routes`, it will tell you which path methods are available.

Comment: I get this. `Started GET "/share/johnsmith.5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-01 12:29:58 +1100`
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/share/johnsmith.5")`

Comment: Why is there a `.` and no `/` in between the name and the id? You obviously have called `http://127.0.0.1:3000/share/johnsmith.5`, but you should have: **`http://127.0.0.1:3000/share/johnsmith/5`**

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. The link is made in the view with this: `share_path(doc.user.ftp, doc)`.